# Can I travel to the northern part of Cyprus?

Tags: cyprus, northern-cyprus

I will fly (with my wife) from Germany to Paphos on the 19th of Feb. I have reserved a hotel on the northern side of cpyrus starting from the 21. Feb.

How long does it take to cross the border with a car?
Is it a problem to cross the border in times of corona?
Is there any other things I should take into consideration?

Comment: What citizenship(s), passport(s), and identity documents do you hold?

Comment: Most countries' governments that provide travel advice from their Foreign Office or similar should cover Northern Cyprus in the page for Cyprus (e.g. with info on COVID, visa/passport requirements, and general safety/health). You'll need to ensure car insurance, health insurance, travel insurance, etc, cover you in the North, as with travelling to any other country. There are several other questions about travelling to Northern Cyprus which you can read, e.g. https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/118559/driving-with-a-rental-car-from-larnaca-to-northern-cyprus.

Comment: We have a German and an Indian passport. But my question was mostly about any issues related to covid and the current situation.